# How to snap a python package with plugin packages?

Tags: python, snapcraft, kedro

I'd like to bundle the Python package `kedro` which provides a command line interface (`kedro`). In addition I'd like to put the Python package `kedro-docker` into the snap as well. This second package extends the first package's command line interface (`kedro docker`). But when I create a snap with the `snapcraft.yaml` below I get only the command line interface of the first package:

```yaml
name: kedro
base: core18
version: latest
description: |
    Kedro is a development workflow framework that implements software
    engineering best-practice for data pipelines with an eye towards
    productionising machine learning models.

grade: devel
confinement: devmode

architectures:
  - build-on: [amd64]

apps:
  kedro:
    command: kedro
    plugs:
      - home
      - network
      - network-bind
      - docker
    environment: {
      LANG: C.UTF-8,
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
    }

parts:
  kedro:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    python-packages:
      - kedro==0.15.9
      - kedro-docker==0.1.1
```

How can I get the extended command line interface (`kedro docker`) into the snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert and never used `snapcraft`, therefore just a hypothesis here. Kedro-Docker exposes only project-specific commands that won't show up unless you are in the root of the project. So if you run `kedro new` and then `cd <project-dir> && kedro`, you should (ideally) see a `docker` group of commands:

```
Global commands from Kedro
Commands:
  docs  See the kedro API docs and introductory tutorial.
  info  Get more information about kedro.
  new   Create a new kedro project.

Project specific commands from Docker
Commands:
  docker  Dockerize your Kedro project.

Project specific commands from <project-dir>/kedro_cli.py
Commands:
  activate-nbstripout  Install the nbstripout git hook to automatically...
  build-docs           Build the project documentation.
  build-reqs           Build the project dependency requirements.
  install              Install project dependencies from both...
  ipython              Open IPython with project specific variables loaded.
  jupyter              Open Jupyter Notebook / Lab with project specific...
  lint                 Run flake8, isort and (on Python >=3.6) black.
  package              Package the project as a Python egg and wheel.
  run                  Run the pipeline.
  test                 Run the test suite.
```

Comment: Great. This solved my issue. I did not know that. Thanks a lot.